# How do I access Azure Mobile App Services from PHP?

Tags: php, json, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have created an app that is able to connect to the Azure Web Services. However, I would like to be able to access the data through a browser, too. Instead of using i.e. Postman, I would like to create a PHP site for this.

While the database is not accessible from the outer web (and I am not planning to change this), I would like to use the same access point that the app uses for queries, the Azure Mobile App. (via http://{...}.azurewebsites.com/tables/{...})

I have done some research and someone suggested to use cURL to handle this. I have built some code:

```
<?php

function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false, $authenticate = false, $username = "", $password = "")
{
    // Initializing cURL
    $curl = curl_init();

    // Setting headers
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array('ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0.', 'Accept: application/json', 'Cache-Control: no-cache'));

    // Set actions based on method
    switch($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            if($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Authentication
    if($authenticate)
    {
        $auth_string = $username.":".$password;
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth_string);
    }

    // Prepare execution
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // Execution
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    // Cleanup
    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}

// $url = "http://•••.azurewebsites.net/tables/users";

$result = CallAPI("GET", $url);

echo $result;

?>
```

However, when I try to execute this, I get only this reply:

```
{"error":"An invalid API version was specified in the request, this request needs to specify a ZUMO-API-VERSION of 2.0.0."}
```

How do I put the header in correctly so that I receive a proper answer? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error in the code. It was a simple dot too much:

```
'ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0.'
```

must be

```
'ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0'
```